I have a list that contains 12 elements. I would like to make a function that subset the list based on a sequence every nth element
I have a list containing 12 data frames. I would like  to subset/split the  list after every third elements based on a sequence. And make a new data frame of the new subsetted list .
 # my_list
  
my_list 
[[1]]...........[[12]]...[[nth]] 
length(my_list) 12

The desired outcome should be like this
df1
df2
df3
df4
df_nth
#Desired outcome

subset1_my_list 
[[1]] 
[[2]] 
[[3]] 
length(subset1_my_list)
 3

subset2_my_list 
[[4]] 
[[5]] 
[[6]] 
lenght(subset2_my_list)
 3


#subset_nth_my_list 
#[[n-2]]  [[n-1]] [[n]]
length(subset_nth_my_list )

I tried this function
my_list_fun  <- function(my_list, nSubsets, n){
 lst <- vector("list", length = nSubsets) to <- length(my_list)


 for (i in seq_len(nSubsets)) {
            subset_n <- seq(i, to, n)
            lst[[i]] <- data[ subset_n ,] 
    }
    return(lst)
}


This seems like an interesting question. You would get better help if you included a reproducible example -- we don't have any data to use based on what you've given us . You can start by adding a sample of your list of 12 data frames. You can do this by running the command dput(lapply(my_list, head)) and copy-pasting the output into your question.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.
